# Как сделать, чтобы у передаваемой песни было нормальное название, а не набор символов?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, аудио, telebot, aiogram

Мой код в разработке(хочу сделать телеграм бота, присылающего музыку из ВК).

При нажатии на кнопку Топ ВК должен отправить песню(ссылку на которую я вставила в код).

Код:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

from telebot import types
from config import token

bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

from aiogram.types import  ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
    
button1 = KeyboardButton('Топ ВК')
button2 = KeyboardButton('Сохраненные плейлисты')
button3 = KeyboardButton('Поиск ')
button4 = KeyboardButton('Учетная запись')
button5 = KeyboardButton('Музыкальные рекомендации')
button6 = KeyboardButton('Новинки')

markup5 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).row(button1, button2, button3)
markup5.row(button4, button5)
markup5.insert(button6)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Что изволите?", reply_markup=markup5)

@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="Топ ВК"))
async def button_top(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, 'https://cs9-11v4.vkuseraudio.net/p2/d57bc18638cddf.mp3?extra=7uNOyzgAUDODxh-NfXnIeBATJuf6IiL35g2hnNhJ_Tw0XEJhVHaFFJuMBqXxhvi3eZQnIo33O327_4Vi38uUkrGGivRwNlgUvtNoSyzEQkaHjSIhy6NDR5wVBHG1CBvh-a2g-dF9apFErtsMo7Gmic41yQ&long_chunk=1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Код работает, но музыкальный файл выводится как набор символов, а не название песни.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно по Вашей ссылке сервер возвращает именно такое название файла. Добавьте дополнительный параметр filename="МояМузычка.mp3" и будет Вам счастье.

Comment: `await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, 'url', title="Название")`

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в send_audio параметр [filename](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/upload_file.html#sending-files)

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="Топ ВК"))
async def button_top(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, 'https://cs9-11v4.vkuseraudio.net/p2/d57bc18638cddf.mp3?extra=7uNOyzgAUDODxh-NfXnIeBATJuf6IiL35g2hnNhJ_Tw0XEJhVHaFFJuMBqXxhvi3eZQnIo33O327_4Vi38uUkrGGivRwNlgUvtNoSyzEQkaHjSIhy6NDR5wVBHG1CBvh-a2g-dF9apFErtsMo7Gmic41yQ&long_chunk=1', filename="ТоповыйТрэк.mp3")
```

Comment: У sendAudio нет параметра filename